# python - how to print Tic Tac Toe game board using for loop

Tags: python

I am new to python. Would like to print the game board for the tic tac toe. May I know how to print using for loop?

[image: The output should be like this]

Here is my code:

`

```
board = {
    1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' ',
    4: ' ', 5: ' ', 6: ' ',
    7: ' ', 8: ' ', 9: ' '
}
def printBoard():
   print(board[1] + '|'+ board[2]+'|'+board[3])
   print('-----')
   print(board[4] + '|'+board[5]+'|' + board[6])
   print('-----')
   print(board[7] + '|'+board[8]+'|' + board[9])
   return
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You just need to call the function at the end of the script so that it actually gets executed. And the return keyword is not needed as the function doesn't return any value, only prints the board.

```
board = {
    1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' ',
    4: ' ', 5: ' ', 6: ' ',
    7: ' ', 8: ' ', 9: ' '
}

def printBoard():
   print(board[1] + '|'+ board[2]+'|'+board[3])
   print('-----')
   print(board[4] + '|'+board[5]+'|' + board[6])
   print('-----')
   print(board[7] + '|'+board[8]+'|' + board[9])

printBoard()
```

Comment: Thank you but sorry, because I need to use for loop to print the board

Answer (score 0):

**You can make a Tic Tac Toe game using the folowing code :**

```
import random

class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []

    def create_board(self):
        for i in range(3):
            row = []
            for j in range(3):
                row.append('-')
            self.board.append(row)

    def get_random_first_player(self):
        return random.randint(0, 1)

    def fix_spot(self, row, col, player):
        self.board[row][col] = player

    def is_player_win(self, player):
        win = None

        n = len(self.board)

        # checking rows
        for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if self.board[i][j] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        # checking columns
        for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if self.board[j][i] != player:
                    win = False
                    break
            if win:
                return win

        # checking diagonals
        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[i][i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win

        win = True
        for i in range(n):
            if self.board[i][n - 1 - i] != player:
                win = False
                break
        if win:
            return win
        return False

        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def is_board_filled(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True

    def swap_player_turn(self, player):
        return 'X' if player == 'O' else 'O'

    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end=" ")
            print()

    def start(self):
        self.create_board()

        player = 'X' if self.get_random_first_player() == 1 else 'O'
        while True:
            print(f"Player {player} turn")

            self.show_board()

            # taking user input
            row, col = list(
                map(int, input("Enter row and column numbers to fix spot: ").split()))
            print()

            # fixing the spot
            self.fix_spot(row - 1, col - 1, player)

            # checking whether current player is won or not
            if self.is_player_win(player):
                print(f"Player {player} wins the game!")
                break

            # checking whether the game is draw or not
            if self.is_board_filled():
                print("Match Draw!")
                break

            # swapping the turn
            player = self.swap_player_turn(player)

        # showing the final view of board
        print()
        self.show_board()

# starting the game
tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe()
tic_tac_toe.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two generator expression, one for row and one for each cell. You can add the separators by using the generators in `join()`

```
def print_board():
    print('\n-----\n'.join(('|'.join(board[i + j] for i in range(1, 4)) for j in range(0, len(board), 3))))
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry because I need to use for loop

Comment: This is using `for`, just in a different style than the "regular" for.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it, thank you very much

Comment: Sir, I will need to print the number of the box if the value is empty as shown in the picture, may I know how can I do that?  @Guy

Comment: Just put the numbers instead of empty string when you create the dictionary.